# Benefit of LLVM's SelectInst

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

LLVM has a `SelectInst` that is used to represent expressions like `something = cond ? true-part : false-part`.

What is the benefit of this instruction in the IR, as `?:` could also always be lowered to a `BranchInst` by the compiler? Are there CPUs that support such instructions? Or is `select` lowered to jumps by the CodeGenerator anyway?

I reckon there may be benefits for analysis passes as the `select` guarantees two "branches" of the implicit `if`. But on the other hand, compilers are not required to use the instruction at all, so these passes must be able to deal with `br`s anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use always use a conditional branch instead of a select instruction, but a select has several advantages:

1. There are indeed relevant CPU instructions to lower those into, the most obvious example in x86 being [cmov](http://www.rcollins.org/p6/opcodes/CMOV.html) and the various [set*cc* instructions](http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2011/readings/i386/SETcc.htm).
2. A select is a lot easier to vectorize - in fact, one of the usual phases of vectorization is "if conversion", the process of converting control flow (a conditional branch) to data flow (a select).

Comment: Yep, ARM also has select instructions in NEON.